# Octave: "sin(x)*cos(x); " brings back error

Tags: functions, almost-periodic-functions

Good day,

I am having little trouble with Octave.

**Description:**

On octave I get following error when multiply tow moving indexes.

```
octave:103> x=[0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
x =

   0   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9


octave:105> sin(x)*cos(x)
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x9, op2 is 1x9)
octave:106>
```

**While on wolframalpha.com** I get nice function:

sin(x)*cos(2*x); x=[0 to 9]

[image]

Comment: The star operator in Octave can be used for two numbers or two matrices. Arrays are considered matrices. You may want the dot star operator.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ".*" instead of "*". The former is the pointwise multiplication, the latter is the vector/matrix/tensor multiplication.